# How to call Asyn function in another async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I convert the below function into the Async function? I have to call few methods based on the outcome of the below function call once isMaxAttemptExceeded is fully executed.

```
        let isMaxAttemptExceeded = () => {
        console.log('called');
        let ret = MyProfileRepository.getProfileByUserID(userEmail);
        ret.then(function (response) {
            //some verification here
            if (userVerifiedCount >= 3) {
                var curDate = moment(new Date().toISOString());
                var diff = curDate.diff(nextDate, 'seconds');
                if (diff > 0) {
                    console.log('diff - ' + diff);
                    setMSG(
                        'You have exceeded maximum allowed limit.Please try after ' +
                            diff / 60 +
                            ' minutes'
                    );
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: You don’t save the then result so currently it’s useless

Comment: You could simply return the promise: `return ret.then(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t save the `then` result so currently it’s useless, but if you want to return the `then` result it would look like this:

```js
let isMaxAttemptExceeded = async () => {
        console.log('called');
        let response = await MyProfileRepository.getProfileByUserID(userEmail);

            //some verification here
            if (userVerifiedCount >= 3) {
                var curDate = moment(new Date().toISOString());
                var diff = curDate.diff(nextDate, 'seconds');
                if (diff > 0) {
                    console.log('diff - ' + diff);
                    setMSG(
                        'You have exceeded maximum allowed limit.Please try after ' +
                            diff / 60 +
                            ' minutes'
                    );
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    };
```

And a cleaned version:

```
let isMaxAttemptExceeded = async () => {
   console.log('called');
   let response = await MyProfileRepository.getProfileByUserID(userEmail);

   //some verification here
   if (userVerifiedCount < 3) 
      return false;
   }
            
            
   var curDate = moment(new Date().toISOString());
   var diff = curDate.diff(nextDate, 'seconds');
   if (diff <= 0) {
      return false;
   }
            
   console.log('diff - ' + diff);
   setMSG(`You have exceeded maximum allowed limit.Please try after ${diff / 60} minutes`);
            
   return true;
};
```